# Highlighted state for UIButton doesn't come when going from selected to normal state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIButton , with 4 different states according to my app.

```
state-1 normal.
state-2 selected.
state-3 highlighted , going normal-to-selected.
state-4 highlighted , going selected-to-normal.
```

Initially button is in normal state, and when I press it it goes to selected state and keep toggling between these states.

this is achieved by specifying images for the two states and changing the selected property.

However, on change of every state I needed to change the highlighted state image to make sure it represents either of state 3 and state 4 while being pressed.

The problem is , while coming from selected to normal, it looks like there is not highlighted state for UIButton.

So for now I keep a BOOL ivar to check the selection state in my View.
and keep the button in normal state and change its image for highlighted state and normal state  with every action based on value of the BOOL ivar.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this is that the state is a mix of two values.

Some of the most commons ones

```
UIControlStateNormal,
UIControlStateHighlighted,
UIControlStateDisabled,
UIControlStateSelected,
UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted,
UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateDisabled,
```

So if you want to have a `highlighted` state when `selected` then I prefer to do like this.

```
    [button setImage:imageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If a general rule is that you always have same highlighted state when selected you can do something along the lines of

```
    UIControlState mixedState = UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted;
    [button setImage:[button imageForState:state] forState:state];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[button backgroundImageForState:state] forState:state];
    [button setTitleColor:[button titleColorForState:state] forState:state];
```

And so on

Comment: So if I keep one image for selected state, one for normal.
one for selected + highlighted and one for just highlighted,
then automatically images will chnage based on state of button without needing a separate boolean ivar?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar Yes, usefull to understand the underlying reason and not just how to fix it. :) regarding your second comment: yep, that's right.

Comment: Just tried this approach and removed my previous code. Looks cleaner.
and works fine.
So when the button goes from normal to selected, and there is highlighted state in between,
UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted mean the same thing ?

Comment: No, `UIControlStateHighlighted` is not equal to `UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted`. But you are always able to check if the state contains `UIControlStateHighlighted` like this: `((self.state & UIControlStateHighlighted) == UIControlStateHighlighted)`

Answer (score 0):

Saving the highlighted state in a Boolean variable is a common way to keep track of the state, however here's something that will simply your code.

There is a `setHighlighted` method that gets called on the UIControl that you can override. You can set your variable in there instead of in multiple actions:

```
-(void)setHighligted:(BOOL) highlighted {
    self.mySavedHighlightedState = highlighted;
}
```

Create a custom UIButton class with a `mySavedHighlightedState` property to implement this.

Comment: `self.isHighlighted` basically only does this `(self.state & UIControlStateHighlighted) == UIControlStateHighlighted`

Comment: @hfossil, I changed the variable name. Didn't mean to hide the `isHighlighted` getter.

Comment: This was really confusing.