# Subclassed UIButton loses highlight

Tags: ios, uibutton

So I've subclassed a UIButton and the only method I've added to it is setTitle (I am using icon fonts so I created an Icon_UIButton for those buttons represented via icons).

I have this code:

```
Icon_UIButton* button = [[Icon_UIButton alloc] init]; 
[button setTitle:@"R"]; //R is a specific icon in my icon font
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This looks like it works, but after I set a button to selected using:

```
[button setSelected:YES];
```

whenever I tap and hold down on that button, it turns black again.

It's like a selected Icon_UIButton ignores it's titleColor for a highlighted state when it's selected at the same time.

Has anybody experienced this?

Comment: yes this is a known issue brought up a few times here, theres a few fixes you can search or ill try and find one real quick.

Comment: Thanks for the response @rezand I googled (what felt like) exhaustively and I came up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the correct answer to my question in this thread:

[Highlighted state for UIButton doesn't come when going from selected to normal state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878555/highlighted-state-for-uibutton-doesnt-come-when-going-from-selected-to-normal-s)

I hate to answer my own question, but just in case anybody else types in search terms that might match this question in google, here is the answer (shortened, but directly from the other thread):

There's another UIControlState (or rather, a mix of control states):

```
UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted
```

So now the code looks like this:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```